# How to add x and y labels for each individual plot subplots when x and y axis is shared?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a 3x3 grid of subplots with shared x and y axis in jupyter notebook.

`fig, ((ax1,ax2,ax3), (ax4,ax5,ax6), (ax7,ax8,ax9)) = plt.subplots(3,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)`

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)
ax5.plot(x,y,'-')enter code here
```

Now when I try to make x and y labels for each individual subplot visible through following code, nothing happens.

```
for ax in plt.gcf().get_axes():
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_visible(True)
```

How do I get x and y labels for each subplot when x and y axis are shared?

Comment: You might need to show a picture of what is occuring and what you are trying to do with your plots. It is a little difficult to discern what you need exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

> When subplots have a shared x-axis along a column, only the x tick labels of the bottom
> subplot are created. Similarly, when subplots have a shared y-axis along a row,
> only the y tick labels of the first column subplot are created.
> **To later turn other subplots' ticklabels on, use [tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)**.

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3, sharex=True, sharey=True, constrained_layout=True)
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True, labelleft=True)
```

[image]